# Как в forEath --> addEventListener обратиться не ко всем элементам

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 6 блоков с одним классом, нужно чтобы при нажатии 5 из 6 из них меняли свой цвет при нажатии, а с одним при нажатии ничего не происходило (например с 3) .
Пример кода:

```js
const block = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

block.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.style.background = 'red';  
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<div class="block">
<div class="block">
<div class="block">
<div class="block">
<div class="block">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь вторым аргументом колбека, индексом элемента:

```js
const block = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

block.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index === 2) return; 
  
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.style.background = 'red';  
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Но, возможно, экономнее будет использовать [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation) — присвоить исключаемому элементу особый класс и проверять его в одном общем обработчике.

Comment: Спасибо, с индексом помогло:)

Answer (score 1):

> чтобы при нажатии 5 из 6 из них меняли свой цвет при нажатии, а с одним при нажатии ничего не происходило

Если *«с одним из них»* == *«с тем, на который нажали»*:

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
const clickHandler = evt => {
  blocks.forEach(block => {
    if (block === evt.target) return;  // пропуск элемента, по которому кликнули
    block.style.background = block.style.background ? '' : 'red';
  });
};
blocks.forEach(block => block.addEventListener('click', clickHandler));
```

```css
body { padding: 20px; text-align: center; }

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.block + .block { margin-left: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

В создании новой функции-обработчика на каждой итерации цикла (как в коде из вопроса), здесь нет смысла. Функцию можно объявить заранее, однократно - а затем добавить в качестве слушателя каждому из элементов. Это конечно не сэкономит великие горы памяти, но лучше сразу привыкать не множить лишние объекты - в будущем это пригодится (например, когда придется использовать `removeEventListener`).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const block = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
const ignoreIndex = 3;

block.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index + 1 === ignoreIndex) 
    return;
    
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.style.background = 'red';       
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```